# "I showed the monkey himself in the mirror". Why is this sentence grammatical?

Tags: pronouns

I am asking this question for a homework assignment where we have to explain why certain uses of reflexive pronouns i.e. himself, herself, are grammatical or ungrammatical.

For one of the questions, we have to explain why the use of the reflexive pronoun "himself" in the sentence "I showed the monkey himself in the mirror" is appropriate.

I read from various online websites that we generally use reflexive pronouns as the direct objects when the subject and object of the sentence refer to the same entity.

However, in this case, I thought that the subject of the sentence is "I" and the object of the sentence is "himself". According to the rule, the sentence "I showed the monkey himself in the mirror" should not be grammatical but it sounds correct nonetheless.

Can anyone offer an explanation for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was the sentence given to you like that or have you constructed it as an example? As a native English speaker I find it awkward at best, if not dowright incorrect. I would say "I showed the monkey _his reflection_ in the mirror" but, as you suggest, "The monkey saw himself in the mirror".

Comment: @BoldBen It’s an awkward example, but the structure is sound enough. The examples in TRomano’s answers are both unquestionably grammatical and not unlikely to be heard in actual usage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the reflexive pronoun in "he showed me myself" correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432674/is-the-reflexive-pronoun-in-he-showed-me-myself-correct) It's relatively uncommon with ***show***, but syntactically I can't see that ***He saw himself in the mirror*** is any different.

Comment: Is this like a classical question tho

Comment: Appropriately enough for a reflexive pronoun, you showed the monkey his reflection in the mirror.

Comment: Interesting - which is the direct object of the verb 'showed' ? I showed to the monkey, himself in the mirror. I showed the monkey, to himself in the mirror.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The difference is that ‘‘***He saw himself in the mirror***’’ *obeys* the textbook rule that the *subject* and the direct object of the sentence refer to the same entity.  By contrast, in the ‘‘showed’’ examples, it’s the direct object and the indirect object.

Answer (score 16):

## tl;dr – Short answer

Your example is grammatical because the reflexive pronoun has an antecedent (a noun phrase with which it is coreferential) and both are complements of the same verb. The antecedent is the indirect object (*IO*) and the reflexive is the direct object (*DO*), and in this construction reflexives are mandatory.

---

## Long answer

#### Types of reflexive pronouns

Reflexive pronouns have various different functions, depending on sentence structure and what the pronoun is governed by. If you have access to it, there is a very thorough description of them in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Rodney Huddleston and Geoffrey K. Pullum (pp. 1483–1499); the following is mostly excerpted from their description.

What *CGEL* calls **basic reflexives** can only be used if there is a close, structural link between the reflexive pronoun and its *antecedent*. The antecedent can be any kind of noun phrase (including a pronoun), and it can be covert as well than overt (i.e., it doesn’t have to actually appear as a word in the sentence) – but there must be a link between the two.<sup>1</sup>

#### Reflexive constructions

The two most common constructions involving basic reflexive pronouns are those where the pronoun and the antecedent are linked –

1. directly through a shared relationship to the same verb (both are [complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(linguistics)) of the verb), or
2. more indirectly through sentence constituents that are somehow related to the same verb.

2 includes a host of syntactically more complex cases, of which the most common is where the reflexive is the object of a preposition and the prepositional phrase as a whole is a complement of the verb (*I was running from myself*). But we don’t need to deal with 2 here, because your example falls under 1.

1 includes all those cases where both entities (pronoun and antecedent) are in themselves complements of the same verb. That verb can be the main verb in a sentence, or it can be in a subordinate clause. The archetypal version is where the antecedent is the subject and the reflexive is the direct object – that’s the one you’ve learnt from your teachers, and the one most online sources will give. But it’s not the whole truth; in fact, it’s only a small part of the whole truth. The fact of the matter is that **it doesn’t really matter what the syntactic function of the two entities is**. Here are some examples of the possible constructions where both antecedent and pronoun are complements of the verb (shown as *antecedent + pronoun*):

- **S**(ubject) **+ D**(irect) **O**(bject)**:** *I injured myself*, *Sue injured herself*
- **S + I**(ndirect) **O:** *I bought myself a book*, *John bought himself a book*
- **S + P**(redicative) **C**(omplement)**:** *I am myself*, *Ann is not feeling herself today*
- **DO + PC:** *I call him himself*<sup>2</sup>
- **IO + DO:** *Art shows us ourselves*

As you may have noticed, the last item on that list (*IO + DO*) fits your example to a T.

**In *I showed the monkey himself in a mirror*, the antecedent is *the monkey*, the indirect object, and the pronoun is *himself*, the direct object. Both are complements of the verb *show*, and it is this close, structural link between the two constituents which requires us to use the reflexive pronoun.**

#### Possible non-reflexives in the same constructions

In many cases, a non-reflexive pronouns can also be used instead of a reflexive pronoun. There are two possible reasons for this: either the reflexive is **optional** (i.e., you can switch between the two with no difference in meaning in a given construction), or it can be **overridden** by a non-reflexive pronoun; in both cases, there is a tendency that non-reflexive forms are more common in the first and second persons and rarer in the third person.

As an example of the former, there are some dialects, especially in the US, where *S + IO* tends to be only optionally reflexive, so <sup>!</sup>*I bought me a car* and *I bought myself a car* are both possible and roughly equivalent. In the rest of the Anglosphere, the former of these is not possible (the raised exclamation mark means ‘non-standard’). In the *IO + DO* construction like your example, however, reflexives are mandatory.

Non-reflexive pronouns which ‘take over’ from reflexive ones are considered by *CGEL* to be part of the same group of *override reflexives* mentioned in note 1. They are called override reflexives because they can be used even where the use of reflexives is mandatory – they quite literally force-override the required form. They occur mostly in informal speech, but are not limited to specific dialects. These non-reflexives add contrast and emphasis: *I injured myself* is a neutral statement that I did something that resulted in an injury to my own body, whereas *I injured **me*** emphasises the contrast between my injuring myself and my injuring someone else.

---

#### Notes:

<sup><sup>1</sup> This is in opposition to **override reflexives**, which do not require any such link and can appear with no antecedent at all. Your example here contains a basic reflexive, so we can skip the override reflexives. An example of an override reflexive would be “Sarah drove John and myself to the park”, where *myself* has no antecedent at all and could just as well have been the regular personal pronoun *me*.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> I can’t think of any reason why this construction shouldn’t be grammatical, but I will note that it is very, very infrequent. I cannot think of an example that sounds natural and likely to ever be uttered in actual speech, but I believe this is because it is exceedingly rare that we ever need to express anything where a direct object has a predicative complement which is a pronoun.</sup>

Comment: A) Don’t you need to refer in some way to word order or hierarchy? E.g “I presented Mary to herself” is fine, but *”I presented herself to Mary” is not. So just being dependents of the same verb isn’t enough. B) The list of constructions is unprincipled. Why those 5? What principles do they follow from? How about “John believed himself to be smart”, “John would like for himself to win”, “John persuaded Mary to love herself”, John seemed to me to be likely to try to kill himself”. These examples are not really well captured by the system.

Comment: @RichardZ A) The reflexive cannot be the antecedent (outside Ireland, at least); that was implied in the phrasing “the reflexive and its antecedent”. B) Your examples are all cases where the reflexive is not a complement of the same verb as the antecedent, i.e., they fall under category 2, which I skipped for brevity because the example in the question does not fall under it. They are of course all dealt with in _CGEL_.

Comment: +1. The Ghost of Christmas Yet to Come shows Scrooge himself in his grave.

Comment: A) "The reflexive cannot be the antecedent" - that does not address my point. I'm talking about ordering between antecedent and reflexive. Why can I say "Himself, he hated" as well as "He hated himself"? Why can I say "I showed the monkey himself" but not *"I showed himself the monkey". You see? To say antecedent and reflexive "both are complements of the same verb" isn't enough. We need a notion like, say, c-command, or alternative. B) My point was the classification is arbitrary and non-exhaustive. So what's the advantage of such a list? "Love yourself!" (imperative) (not in list), etc.

Comment: So according to CGEL "Thank you for inviting Bill and myself" is acceptable? I thought it was considered a case of hypercorrection. This question asks a similar question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233144/esl-text-i-notice-similarities-between-myself-and-acceptable-use-of-r , though the answer doesn't seem to help me as the examples are all different from the OP's question. It's possible that this unnecessary use of "myself" instead of "me" is becoming less common, as suggested in a comment, with their "decade-long preference" remark.

Comment: @RichardZ A) “Himself he hated” is emphatic fronting, which is completely unrelated. More or less anything can be fronted for emphasis. I don’t see how the order of antecedent and anaphor is relevant either, but to my knowledge, reflexive anaphors cannot be anticipatory in non-subordinated constructions. If c-command answers the question of why the antecedent and anaphor must be ordered this way in this construction, your answer does not address it either; I don’t see what the difference is.

Comment: @RichardZ B) The list is neither arbitrary nor non-exhaustive. The _examples_ are, of course, but I don’t see how they could not be. “Love yourself!” is quite clearly _S + DO_, with a covert subject (which, as mentioned further up, is possible). What combination of verb complements that are fillable by a reflexive pronoun is missing from the list?

Comment: @Zebrafish Yes, perfectly acceptable. I know it annoys some people because it’s unnecessary (in some cases at least), but there is no basis for calling it ungrammatical. I don’t even think it makes sense to call it a hypercorrection.

Comment: Under which rule or guideline does CGEL say that it's acceptable to use an "override reflexive" pronoun such as in "Thank you for inviting Bill and myself"? Or does it just say it's fine to use "myself" whenever "me" is normally used? I don't understand the reasoning behind this. Is it the same in "They interrogated myself and John" or "They interrogated myself"? Which ones of these do they consider wrong, if any?

Comment: A) Yes, it's this statement "reflexive anaphors cannot be anticipatory in non-subordinated constructions" that I was getting at. That aspect, "anticipation", "relative order between antecedent and anaphor", "hierarchy", or call it what you will, could be a good addition to your answer.

Comment: B) Well, it's your answer. But I think the answer would be improved by not referring to arbitrary lists (it's not based on general principles). And it's not exhaustive. It has 1)S-DO, 2)S-IO and 5) IO-DO. How about 2+5) S-IO-DO, "God gave himself to himself / God gave himself himself"? With 4) DO+PC - which is actually bi-clausal, "I call [him=subject, himself=predicate]", why not the inverse as a type, "He thought [himself=subject, intelligent=predicate] (it's different from 1; it means 'he = intelligent', not 'he thinks himself').

Comment: How about added arguments, "She ran herself out of breath". How about absolute clauses? "Herself naked near him, she wanted to barf" (Songs without words, 2007). But most importantly, the artificial requirement to only look at instances where anaphor and antecedent  directly dependent on the same verb ignores a huge number of cases of binding.

Comment: I think the moderators don't like it when the comments lead to long discussions like this. So, we could move this conversation to a private chat...

Answer (score 3):

Within Generative Grammar frameworks, e.g. Government and Binding (Chomsky 1981), the answer to your question would run along the following lines:

The word "himself" is a reflexive anaphor. Such anaphors distribute according to [Binding Principle A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_(linguistics)). Binding Principle A states: 
**An anaphor must be bound by an antecedent locally within its binding domain. Being bound means c-commanded, sharing in appropriate features, and co-indexed. A binding domain in English is, roughly, a clause with a subject position.**

In your example, the conditions given in Binding Principle A are met. Therefore, the sentence is explained as grammatical. 
<sub>(However, I find "show X Y" much worse than "show X to Y". "I showed Bill Mary" just like "I showed Bill himself" is worse for me than "I showed Bill to Mary" or "I showed Bill to himself". I'm therefore going to add "to" here)</sub>

- The anaphor "himself" is bound by "the monkey" because it is [c-commanded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-command) by it, it shares the features 3rd person singular, masculine, and can be co-indexed, shown by subscript *i*.

> (1) [I showed [ [the monkey]<sub>*i*</sub> [to himself<sub>*i*</sub> ]]]
> ("the monkey"=antecedent, which correctly binds "himself"=anaphor)

Note, if any of the conditions are violated the sentence is correctly predicted to become ungrammatical. So, if the anaphor is not c-commanded by the antecedent, the sentence becomes impossible.

> (2) *[[I showed [the monkey]<sub>*i*</sub> around] [by swinging himself<sub>*i*</sub> over my head]] 
> ("the monkey" does not c-command "himself")

If the anaphor does not share the right features with the antecedent, the sentence also becomes impossible.

> (3) *[I showed [the monkey]<sub>*i*</sub> to themselves<sub>*i*</sub>] 
>  ("the monkey" is 3rd person singular, but "themselves" is 3rd person plural)

- The anaphor "himself" is bound within its local binding domain. This domain, here, is simply the entire clause because that's where the subject "I" occurs (simplified).

> (4) [<sub>binding domain</sub>I showed [the monkey]<sub>*i*</sub> to himself<sub>*i*</sub> ]
> ("himself" is bound locally, WITHIN its binding domain)

Again, if this requirement is not met, the sentence becomes ungrammatical. For example, in the sentence below, the anaphor is not bound within its local binding domain - the antecendet is "too far" away - and so the sentence is impossible.

> (5) *[I showed [the monkey]<sub>*i*</sub> that [<sub>binding domain</sub> bananas are good for himself<sub>*i*</sub> ]]
> ("himself" is not bound locally, OUTSIDE of its binding domain)

---

(Examples of this kind, ditransitives with indirect objects binding a direct object anaphor, are important because they are used as evidence for certain structural assumptions, i.e. for an aysmmetric structure of objects within the VP, for verb movement, for VP shells, or for little *v*P.)

Comment: Note: if you add _to_ and the two NPs are not coreferential, you have to remember to switch the NPs as well. _I showed Bill Mary_ and _I showed Bill to Mary_ mean the opposite of each other.

Comment: Yes, I think so. But I think the reading with “to” is what the original monkey-sentence meant.

Comment: Well, in the original example they are coreferential, so you can switch them around at will – since the reflexive must always be the anaphor, not the antecedent, switching them around will also automatically switch around the form (“the monkey” vs “himself”). It’s only when the two are not coreferential that the switch must be made overtly.

Comment: No, you cannot switch them around. *"I showed himself the monkey" is ungrammatical.

Comment: I am not talking about switching the surface form, but the _reference_. Switching the reference of two coreferentials does not change anything but the numeric index of each reference (_I showed [the monkeyᵢ₁] [himselfᵢ₂]_ becomes _I showed [the monkeyᵢ₂] [himselfᵢ₁]_). This is different from non-coreferentials, where switching the reference by force entails switching the surface form as well (_I showed [Billᵢ] [Maryⱼ]_ cannot become _I showed [Billⱼ] [Maryᵢ]_). But switching references alone does not permit violating constrictions on anaphora anticipation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this statement is non-sensical. Coreference *by definition* means that antecedent and anaphor have the SAME index.  *I showed [the monkeyᵢ₁] [himselfᵢ₂] is ungrammatical, "the monkey" and "himself" must bear the same index to be co-referential. Are you possibly confusing reference and thematic roles? I showed Bill = Experiencer Mary = Theme. I showed Bill = Theme to Mary = Experiencer. I cannot make sense of your comment otherwise.

Comment: I used _reference_ instead of _index_ to refer to the object being indexed/referenced (i.e., the physical entities of Bill, Mary and the monkey), in order to separate it from the mathematical meaning of _index_ (sequential array numbering) also used in the sentence. The subscript letters refer to different contextual entities being referenced (linguistic index); the subscript numbers refer to the order or sequence of multiple references to the same entity. I.e., [the monkey(i1)] and [himself(i2)] both reference the same monkey, but appear as reference #1 and #2 to it.

Comment: So my point was that if you switch the reference between two coreferentials, you are only switching between “this word references entity X for the first time” with “this word references entity X for the second time”; that is a trivial substitution which has no effect on the semantic content of the word, since both point to the same thing. If you do the same with non-coreferentials, the actual reference/index to the contextual entity is changed, resulting in a sentence with a different meaning.

Comment: I find your comment extremely difficult to understand. You're saying that your "index of reference" (never heard that term before) is a numbered list of when reference is assigned? What is that good for? Since referring is an act (Searle), how do you know WHEN a linguistic item was given a reference? Also, why would that be different for "non-coreferentials" (another term that I've never encountered)? "I showed Bill i 1 Mary j 2" means the same as  "I showed Bill i 2 Mary j 1" except I first assign reference to Mary, then I assign reference to Bill. (What is ⱼ above?")

Answer (score 2):

We could say that "Art shows us ourselves in its mirror". I think that's grammatical, and by analogy, "I showed the monkey itself in the mirror" would be grammatical, but I think many native speakers would avoid it and say "its image" instead of "itself". Maybe that's because of the monkey. This seems fine to me:

> The town's most popular dressmaker was accused of showing customers themselves in mirrors that flatter.

though I suspect a good number of speakers would choose to say it this way:

> The town's most popular dressmaker was accused of showing customers to themselves in mirrors that flatter.

Comment: Yeah, among other problems, "monkey himself" has a minor "garden path" problem, in that initially most listeners would assume that "himself" is being used as an intensifier of "monkey".

Comment: I thought what allows reflexive personal pronouns when subject and object are NOT the same is the use of it for emphasis/intensifer pronoun, as in "Give me that! I'll do it myself." Also, shouldn't it be "Art shows us our selves in its mirror"? I don't think I'm understanding how these are right.

Comment: @Zebrafish: So you'd say "their selves" rather than "themselves"? And "I looked at my [space] self in the mirror"?

Comment: I'd definitely say I looked at 'myself' in the mirror,' as 'myself' is the suitable reflexive pronoun for that (same subject and object). For the art sentence, I thought the idea is that art shows me my self, shows him his self, shows you your self, and so shows us our selves. Using the reflexive personal pronoun 'ourselves' here sounds wrong to me. I know also they can be used as intensive pronouns, as in "I'll do it myself". I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: @Zebrafish If use _self_ as a noun (“Shows them their selves”), the meaning changes. If the mirror just shows the reflection of the personal looking into it, as mirrors tend to do, the reflexive pronoun is what you’ll need. The noun would be appropriate if you were referring to the observer’s individuality, nature, character, etc. (as in ‘sense of self’).

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer about why it is grammatical, but to show the actual usage of the phrase. Note that the monkey is referred to by "him", not "it". My reading of the sentence is the speaker talking about a man whom (s)he is likening to a monkey. The speaker showed this man his true nature either through an act which made him reflect, or by reflecting his behavior him/herself to show him "look, this is how you behave". The mirror is a metaphor. The original sentence, in my opinion, can be rephrased as "oh I showed him what a monkey he really is".

So yes, not only does the sentence grammatically sound as others have explained wonderfully, but the usage also makes perfect sense to me in the right context.

Answer (score 0):

"[to] the monkey" is an indirect object;
"himself in the mirror" is the direct object.
("to" is used only to clarify the indirect nature.)
One could say "... show [to] himself the monkey in the mirror"; but (1) it is not idiomatic; and because of the phrase "in the mirror", it becomes very misleading, even ambiguous.  Besides, putting "the monkey in the mirror" before "to the monkey" merely exacerbates that problem.
As soon as you see what the parts are doing, you see that it is grammatical.
One cannot really say "show the monkey the monkey in the mirror" for this usage; it would suggest that the mirror is showing a different monkey.